# geom line: set manual color for variables that are grouped

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, manual

I've data set with three columns as below

```
data_sample<-data.frame(value=c(-3,-2,-1,-0.9,-1.25,1.0,2.1,1.9,1.2,1.5),
BP=c(1000,2000,5000,8000,10000),variable=c(rep("overall_diff_cases",5),rep("overall_diff_controls",5)))
```

where BP is base pair, for each position, there's value in variable column: overall_diff_controls and overall_diff_cases. I'm interested in creating a `geom_line` `ggplot` graph using these points.

```
ggplot(data_sample, aes(x=BP, y=value, group =variable,color=variable)) +
scale_fill_manual(values= c("overall_diff_cases"="#9633FF" ,"overall_diff_controls"="#E2FF33")) + geom_line(size=1.2)
```

If I use the above code, ggplot creates plot with default color. I tried with color code (non hexa decimal)

`scale_fill_manual(values= c("overall_diff_cases" = "red" , "overall_diff_controls" = "black"))`

I tried setting up `setNames` but in vain:

```
ggplot(data_sample, aes(x=BP, y=value, group = variable,color=variable)) +
scale_fill_manual(values=setNames(c("overall_diff_cases","overall_diff_controls"), c( "black","red"))) +
 geom_line(size=1.2)
```

How do I set the colors of my interests? The data format needs to stay as shown in the same data frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data_sample, aes(x=BP, y=value,
                        group =variable,color=variable)) +
  scale_color_manual(values= c("overall_diff_cases"="#9633FF" ,
                               "overall_diff_controls"="#E2FF33")) + geom_line(size=1.2)
```

Output:

[image]

With `scale_color_manual()` you can set the colors you want.